# google-services.json generate wrong ios_info bundle_id string

Tags: android, ios, json, firebase, plist

i have a firebase project that has an android and an ios app inside.

- andoid package name: com.ramobile.myapp
- ios bundle id: com.ramobile.myapp

here is a clip of the google-service.json i download:

```
"appinvite_service": {
      "other_platform_oauth_client": [{
          "client_id": "xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 2,
          "ios_info": {
            "bundle_id": "com.ramobile.myapp"
          }
        } ]
    }
```

Someday i create/add a new ios app with with new bundle id: **com.ramobile.newapp**,
and then shortly after that, i "remove the app", and download the google-service.json again, but the **bundle_id** of the **ios_info** is still refrerring to the latest (deleted) ios app bundle id.

```
"appinvite_service": {
      "other_platform_oauth_client": [{
          "client_id": "xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 2,
          "ios_info": {
            "bundle_id": "com.ramobile.newapp"
          }
        } ]
    }
```

i have refreshed the page and download the file many times, but the result still the same.
is it normal?
it should be the same with the first one, right?

anybody help me, please?

Comment: Since we can't see what specifically you're doing, it might be helpful if you edit the question to walk through the steps you're taking, showing screenshots of the console as you go.  We need to be able to observe what you observe.

Comment: don't mess both app in one project. create another project in console for iOS and generate the config json file.

Comment: I am facing same issue,
i have two projects, one ios and one android
both have same bundle ID com.kf.xxxxxxxxx
when i download google-services.json for android, it shows different bundle_id under ios_info section

is there a way to update google-services.json, without removing the project ?

Answer (score 4):

I was using flutter with firebase authentication and changed my package name/bundle id afterwards. Google Cloud saved my old bundle id under `Google Cloud Console > APIs & Services > Credentials`, accessible here:

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

You have to delete the OAuth 2.0 Client ID which contains your old bundle id.